# SQL Insert performance question

Tags: sql, insert

I have this table phonebook SQL Server 2005:

```
username(PK) Serial(PK) contact_name  contact_adr      contact_email  contact_phone 
bob          1           Steve         12 abc street    steve@bb.com   1234          
bob          2           John          34 xyz street    john@bb.com    5345          
bob          3           Mark          98 ggs street    mark@bb.com    1234          
patrick      4           lily          77 fgs street    lily@bb.com    1234          
patrick      5           mily          76 fgs street    mily@bb.com    1234          
von          8           jim           6767 jsd way     jim@bb.com     4564
```

Now you can see the phonebook stores all contacts of same user together.
Storing this way has advantages which I can't avoid.

My question is:
If I have 100 million entries in the table for all users, will my future insertion in the above table be very expensive?

Since SQL Engine needs to find the actual location where to enter the data (I mean under which username)

I tested with 1 million rows, I don't see noticeable issues.

I am asking if anyone has this experience or suggestions for me?

Thanks

Comment: Which SQL software would you be using? (Also, 'PK' implies a unique index over the column, so I guess that's a foreign key (FK) you mean by "username", and 'serial' is your real primary key (PK) )

Comment: Primary key with duplicate data ?

Comment: I missed on the PK. PK is the (UserName + Serial)

Comment: You cannot assume that this data is sorted based on PK alone, make sure you still specify an ORDER BY in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that is optimal for an address book is a NOSQL hashed-table.  There's no need for an index on the PK. The algorithm returns the "page" where the row identified by the PK can be found. The address book of the user is also stored with the user, as a denormalized relation.  Insert overhead is negligible. Hashed-PK is optimized for insert/retrieval when the PK is known. Excellent for OLTP systems.  Now if you want to do something like figure out who knows whom, so that a given user's contacts need to be related to the contacts of all other users, then you have a different can of worms. But a straightforward address-book application, where the contacts of a given user remain "private" to that user, then a hashed primary key system is superb.

Comment: Sounds promising. Is that specific to MySQL db or Oracle? Do you have good example or urls to look? No seeing this is used much in sql server

Comment: The big question: This approach seems good only when you build the phonebook in one shot and enter the data in ordered fashion. Then you don't need the PK. Buy My case, the phonebook will grow slowly. I must have a PK

Comment: @projapati - He is suggesting you use an entirely different database storage system. With that table structure, you aren't leveraging any relational pros anyway. Might as well just go for NoSQL. Or create the table using proper relations. User, UserAddress, UserPhone, UserEmail, etc.

Comment: @projapati: it doesn't matter when new data are added, as long as you know the username of the person who owns the addressbook. The unique username (e.g. an email address) is the PK.  You can instantly retrieve the addressbook for the user, and insert, update, or delete contacts. You are never going to sort all contacts across all users, or do aggregate functions, etc etc; each little addressbook is its own universe; so there is really no advantage to storing the data relationally, but many disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first principles in db design is data non-redundancy: your db table design doesn't comply to that principle as you have same data repeated many times. A resonable solution would be to create separate table for users, a separate table for contacts and a table for realationship between users and contacts.

Comment: UserName is FK. I have the usernames and account details in another table

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the underlying database. Every implementation has something different under its sleeves.

But! Performance will almost definitely suffer if you use indexes on that table and you have many, many, many, many rows inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, username doesn't seem to be a primary key for your table by itself. You will probably have to use it in combination with another field if you want it to work. At this point, I would rather use your `serial` column as primary key, and have an index on `username` to answer the query *get bob's contacts* efficiently.

You insert will certainly become slower as your table grow. But I don't think it will be too slow to avoid following this approach.

Comment: Why don't you just use `serial` as your primary key?

Comment: what advantage do you see having Serial as the PK? Disadvantages: I will need another gigantic index on username, Most of my queries will be to get the contacts of a given user. I need direct seek.

Comment: @projapati - you should have a nonclustered index on username anyways if you are using just it (and not your serial) in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the data to be stored together. Are you re-sequencing the Serial upon an insert? How are you ensuring the data is "stored together"?

If you mean putting all this data in one table, then it really depends on your index structure. The more indexes on the table, the more processing that takes place on very insert. Since user tables are usually heavily queried and rarely inserted (relatively), they are usually indexed heavily, in which case inserts can be slow. The answer, as with almost every DB question is: "It depends".

Comment: I corrected the table definition. The PK is (UserName + Serial) This stores the entries sorted by PK